# how to specify path and filename while creating a excel file in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

i am able to create an excel file by using this:

```
protected void excldwnlbtn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    write_on_excel();
}

public void write_on_excel()
{
    Excel.ApplicationClass excelApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
    try
    {

        Excel.Workbook workbook = (Excel.Workbook)excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet;






        // Get first Worksheet
        worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);

        // Setting cell values

        ((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[1, "A"]).Value2 = "Vendor Code";
        ((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[1, "B"]).Value2 = "Vendor Password";
        ((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[1, "C"]).Value2 = "Vendor Name";


        workbook.Save();
        workbook.Close(0, 0, 0);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        lblmsg4.Text = "File not Downloaded!!";
    }
    finally
    {
        excelApp.Quit();
    }
}
```

by this i am creating a .xlsx file in my c:\documents as book1.xlsx but i want to specify the folder path and file name how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Save As](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

workbook.SaveAs(@"c:\documents\book1.xlsx",
            Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, missing, missing,
            false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
            missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
```

Comment: should i put false instead of missing ?

Comment: you need to import using System.Reflection;.It represents a missing object normally used in excel interops

Comment: i included it i am using `Missing missing;` i am using this for the 1st time so i don't know what else to do

Comment: @Codelgnoto one more thing its saving the file as XML format how i can save it as .xlsx format? when i am specifying that then the file is not opening

Comment: oops tht was my fault,i have made the changes now.More info here on choosing the excel version to save with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat(v=office.11).aspx